# NullPointerException: нерректно работает программа при вызове через командную строку

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. У меня проблема, при запуске из нетбинса программа корректно запускается и работает, но когда я пытаюсь запустить программу через командную строку выскакивает ошибка `NullPointerException` при выполнении запроса к базе данных.
Вот код метода где выскакивает ошибка:

```
public static ResultSet getResultSetFromBD(String tableName) throws SQLException {

    con = DBConnection.getConnection("BD/museum.db");

    statement = con.createStatement();

    rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT KN as \"КН\"," + "ZH as \"Ж\","
            + "Akt_number as \"Акт №\",image as \"Розташування\" FROM " + tableName + " order by Akt_number");
    return rs;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем тут дело, как так с нетбинса все работает, а когда сам jar файл запускаешь ошибка появляется).

Answer (score 2):

смею предположить что `DBConnection.getConnection("BD/museum.db");` не находит базу данных и возвращает null от того `con.createStatement();` и кидает исключение.

беда в том что есть два адреса программы

- откуда она запускается
- где она
     находится

и они могут отличаться если программу запускать от имени системы

в винде например это будет J:\folder\ (где находится программа) и C:\Windows\System32 (откуда она запускается) если запускать от имени администратора